# Python program don't work properly from LabVIEW, but works itself

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization, scipy, labview

I have a python program which makes some optimization via *scipy.optimize.differential_evolution(...)*. My python program works properly if I launch it via double-click or PyCharm (using system interpreter, Python 3.6.8). But If I try to launch it from LabVIEW 2019 (32-bit) by Python Node, I have a mistake with differential_evolution method. The problem is in differential_evolution method because the mistake vanishes when I turn off this method. The problem can't be in input (from LabView) arguments because I don't use these LabView arguments in my function now.
My function which I call is shown on the below snippet:

```
def make_in_labview()
#initialization of constants like bounds for optimization e. t. c.
...
# Main problem:
    result = sp_opt.differential_evolution(func=myClass.deviation, bounds=optimization_bounds, args=[[empiric_set, funcs, False]],
                                           strategy='best1bin', maxiter=10, tol=0.0001, popsize=30,
                                           mutation=0.35, recombination=0.7, workers=2)

# (sp_opt - scipy.optimize)
    return 0
```

**Here is main mistake which LabView outputs:**

*Function Name: make_tomography
Python returned the following error: <class 'AttributeError'>
module 'sys' has no attribute 'argv'*

**And here is seemingly unuseful Stack information about problem's source**

*Call Stack information:
File "C:\Users...\main.py", line 3171, in make_tomography
result = chip.optimization_diff_evolution(optimization_bounds, [empiric_set, funcs, False])

File "C:\Users...\main.py", line 564, in optimization_diff_evolution
mutation=0.35, recombination=0.7, workers=2)

File "C:\Users\QPrac\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize_differentialevolution.py", line 307, in differential_evolution
constraints=constraints) as solver:

File "C:\Users\QPrac\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize_differentialevolution.py", line 501, in **init**
self._mapwrapper = MapWrapper(workers)

...

e.t.c. similarly or about multiprocessing like

File "C:\Users\QPrac\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 119, in Pool
context=self.get_context())*

Can you help me to understand the problem?

P.S. Also, I have only python 3.6.8., 32-bit (as It needs to work properly with LabVIEW 32-bit) I installed on my Windows. My Windows is 64-bit, but I haven't an opportunity to install LabVIEW 64-bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been solved: if you use LabView's python node, you should to accurately check how you pass additional arguments (i. e. 'args' according to scipy manual) to the diff evolution method of scipy.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).